# How to add delay in callbackFlow

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

Firebase library uses callback and I converted it to flow as below.
In the code below, if I don't add the `delay` and uncomment the `channel.close` everything works as it is.

But when I run the code below, it doesn't come under the delay line.
So I get the below output.

```
Read-Before Await
Read-Success
```

If the callback function is not called in 10 seconds, I want to emit `Resource.Error(Exception("Timeout"))` and `close the channel`.

### OK

```
    override fun read(id: String): Flow<Resource<DataSnapshot>> = callbackFlow {
        database.child(id).get().addOnSuccessListener {
            Timber.d("Read-Success")
            trySend(Resource.Success(it))
            channel.close()
        }.addOnFailureListener {
            Timber.d("Read-Failure")
            trySend(Resource.Error(it))
            channel.close()
        }
        Timber.d("Read-Before Await")
        awaitClose {
            Timber.d("Read-In Await")
        }
        Timber.d("Read-after Await")
    }
```

### FAIL

```
    override fun read(id: String): Flow<Resource<DataSnapshot>> = callbackFlow {
        database.child(id).get().addOnSuccessListener {
            Timber.d("Read-Success")
            trySend(Resource.Success(it))
            //channel.close()
        }.addOnFailureListener {
            Timber.d("Read-Failure")
            trySend(Resource.Error(it))
            //channel.close()
        }
        Timber.d("Read-Before Await")
        delay(10000)  
        trySend(Resource.Error(Exception("timeout")))
        channel.close()
        awaitClose {
            Timber.d("Read-In Await")
        }
        Timber.d("Read-after Await")
    }
```

Comment: This shouldn’t be a flow in the first place because it only emits a single item. You could just use the `await()` suspend function.

Answer (score 0):

You can launch coroutine with delay from `callbackFlow`

```
launch {
    delay(10_000)
    channel.close(TimeoutException())
}
```

Full code [here](https://gist.github.com/aleien/73cadc7f417cf8f8027af0a5d58a4728)